# Jquery and JSON no result

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've made a test fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BjLdQ/2

Where I can enter the number 1 for each HTML field and then I press the login button and I get the JSON back as:

```
{"code":"2"}
```

So in my mind, I should be able to do the same with jQuery so I press the (Login Jquery Ajax) text and nothing happens, in jsfiddle or from my local machine?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually JSLint your code before you submitted this question? Your fiddle has errors.

Comment: Also, I get this error in the console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.searchningbo.com/user/login. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Answer (score 5):

[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)... You cannot fetch pages from a different origin ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)).

See [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) for work-arounds.

Comment: So if i put my javascript on the domain https://api.searchningbo.com all will be ok?

Do I need to have the html, javascript and jquery files all on the same domain?

Comment: @Bill The origin is determined by the location of the (HTML) page. Place your html file at `hhtps://api.searchningbo.com/` (same PROTOCOL, `https` and DOMAIN `api.searchningbo.com`), and the error will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the code.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
     alert("Sending");

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: "{'username':'1','password':'1','key':'1','device_Id':'1'}",
            url: "https://api.searchningbo.com/user/login",
            // This was here: },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);          

            }

        });
} // It wasnt closed properly
```